# Load scripts for do_shortcode( ' [ my_shortcode ] ' )

Tags: functions, shortcode, scripts

I want load some scripts and style only for a specific shortcode. I used

```
if ( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my_shortcode') ) {}
```

It works when I put my shortcode on page but it does not work when I put my shortcode in page template. Like the following one in **index.php** file:

```
echo do_shortcode( ' [ my_shortcode ] ' );
```

Is there any way to load scripts for **[ my_shortcode ]** in **do_shortcode(' [ my_shortcode ] ')** without checking page template.

Comment: Have you tried reading the page template then? there's [`get_page_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template) to get the template path for current page, e.g `print_r( has_shortcode(file_get_contents(get_page_template()), "my_shortcode") );`

Answer (score 2):

Add a filter to `pre_do_shortcode_tag` and check if $tag is the same as your shortcode tag. If it is, enqueue a script in the footer.

```
add_filter( 'pre_do_shortcode_tag', function( $a, $tag, $attr, $m ) {
  if( 'my_shortcode_tag' === $tag ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer = true );
  }
  return $a;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way to enqueue or load your scripts first register the script or styles with `wp_register_style` and `wp_register_script`.

After registering you can load the script/style when required. For example when you render a shortcode with wp_enqueue_style("your_style") and wp_enqueue_script("your_script").

**Example**

```
[my_shortcode other parameters]
```

Add action for the script by registering and enqueuing when required.

```
function prefix_my_shortcode_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'my-shortcode-script', plugins_url( 'path/myscript.css' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_my_shortcode_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Your shortcode function

```
function prefix_function_my_shortcode( $attributes ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(
    // your shortcode array args
   ));

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-shortcode-script' );

    return 'your shortcode output;
}

add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'prefix_function_my_shortcode' );
```

Hope that answers your question. Let me know if that helps out.

Comment: Loading script in shortcode will work but style will not work. Because style load before running shortcode.